# Controller syntax in PHP symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

The demo application I downloaded from php symfony site, has following syntax for controller:

```
_controller:  Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Template::hello
```

and

```
_controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Template::templateAction
```

The relative path for file is app\config\routing.yml.

The reference pages that are mentioned in that file do not have double-colon\scope resolution operator syntax. Is this a valid syntax?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Is this a valid syntax?* Since it's included in a file provided by Symfony, it will probably work.

Comment: You can read here about [Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html)